# Protobuf.Net: Serializing List<Uri> throws "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Uri' to type 'System.String'"

Tags: serialization, protobuf-net

The title says it all, Protobuf.net correctly serializes `Uri`, but won't serialize `List<Uri>`

```
[ProtoContract]
class SingleUri
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public Uri Uri { get; set; }
}
[ProtoContract]
class MultiUri
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public List<Uri> Uris { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var single = new SingleUri { Uri = new Uri("http://www.google.com") };
    using (var file = File.Create("single.bin"))
        // Works a treat
        Serializer.Serialize(file, single);

    var multi = new MultiUri { Uris = new List<Uri> { single.Uri } };
    using (var file = File.Create("multi.bin"))
        // fails with System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object 
        //of type 'System.Uri' to type 'System.String'.
        Serializer.Serialize(file, multi); 
}
```

I'm running this against the latest NuGet package as of time of writing.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here? Any workaround for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Interesting. I'm not aware of this - sounds like a bug. I will look. One workaround would be: store strings in your DTO, not Uri objects :)

Comment: Thanks Marc, I feel bad that it's not somthing I'm doing, Pb.net is an excellent tool, thanks for rolling it, sorry to bring trouble to your door mate.

Comment: Looks like the issue described here: https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/issues/11 Worked around it like suggested by @Marc, even though `System.Uri` is handy in enforcing the use of valid URIs, and even FxCop is nagging when `System.String` is used for properties named like URIs, so a solution would be desirable.